# Use JButton as an Image

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

So, the problem I'm facing is that I want to take JButton's image model, and use it as an image instead. I have not worked with implementing Icons in swing before, so I decided to do some searching. However, I couldn't find anything to make sense what is happening here.

I've tried the following code:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Text");
JLabel buttonIcon = new JLabel(button.getIcon());
```

However, when I go to display the JLabel, nothing appears. Is this interaction wrong?

I would also be satisfied with saving JButton's Model as an image format, and importing it as such.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm sort of confused what you want to achieve. Do you want to display the `Icon` of a `JButton` inside a `JLabel`? Or do you want to display an image of a `JButton` in a `JLabel`? BTW, `JButton` does not extend `JLabel`, so `JLabel buttonIcon = new JButton(button.getIcon());` will throw an error.

Comment: @LukasRotter Sorry, that was a typo. I have fixed the part where I was trying to set JLabel to a JButton.

I basically want to take the look the JButton has, and create it as an object that can't be interacted with.

Edit: Display the Jbutton image in a JLabel

Comment: You should be able to paint the JButton to an Image and set that on the JLabel.  Another option would be to change the UI class of the JLabel so it ends up painting the image the same way as it does on the button.

Comment: You can also check out [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) for a reusable class to get the image of a component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So if you want to snapshot a visible component and display it inside a `JLabel`, you can

1. Set the button's `size` to it's `preferredSize`.
2. Create a `BufferedImage`.
3. Call `button.paint(image.createGraphics())` to draw the button onto the image.
4. Set the `Icon` of the `JLabel` to a new one containing the image.

---

Here's an example (thanks to camickr who [helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067572/use-jbutton-as-an-image/41068326#comment69344827_41068326) make the process cleaner):

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example {

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Text");
        button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize());

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(snapshot(button)));

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(label);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private BufferedImage snapshot(Component component) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        component.paint(image.createGraphics());
        return image;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Example().createAndShowGUI());
    }
}
```

Comment: (1+) but to make the process a little cleaner 1) there is no need to repaint the label. A Swing component will invoke `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on itself when a property is changed. 2) There is no need to add the button to the panel to get an image of it. You need to a) use `button.setSize(button.getPreferredSize()` and b) change paintAll(...) to `paint(...)`.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you very much Lukas and camickr!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
File imgFile=new File("img.jpeg");
Image img=ImageIO.read(imgFile);
ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
JButton button=new JButton();
JLabel label=new JLabel();
button.setIcon(icon);
label.setIcon(button.getIcon());
```

Comment: I downvoted this because the OP wants to display an image of the actual button, not the `icon` of the button.